# Side By Side Photos - Setting Them So That They Are Responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive, photo

I have two photos on a page that I've set so that they're lined up against one another. In order to make this web page easier to navigate through on a smartphone, I'd like to have the two photos line up one on top of another when the screen size shrinks.

If anyone knows how to make photos responsive so that they're lined up one on top of another and easier to view on small-screen devices, as well as to help space the images, I'd appreciate your advice.

![How I'd like my page to look on smaller devices][1]

```
My (revised) code is as follows:
    
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en; jp;">     
    
<body style="background-color: white;">
      
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
      
<div class="page-wrap">
     
<div class="cp_cont">
<input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="cp_mobilebar">
<label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
<label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
<div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>
        
<header class="cp_offcm03">
        
<nav>
<ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">
            
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">ホーム</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">ブログ</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">小泉ついて</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">参考文献</a></li>
    
            
<div class="searchbar"> 
            
<form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: right; position: inline;"/>
<input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="center: 396px; top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;"/>
<input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="検索" style=" padding-  
bottom:20px; left: 0px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 32px;"/>
<input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html"/>    
    
    
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
 window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:yoursitename.com ' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        return false;
    }
    
 document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
 if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
}    
    
</script>
         
</div> 
</ul>    
</nav>
</header>     
               
<div class="setsumei">
        
</div>
        
<br><div class="image" style="margin: 10px; text-align: center;">
    
<div class="responsive-image-container">   
<a href="#"><img src="photos/Home_Page/fuji.JPG" alt="Fuji" width="40%"></a>&nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="photos/Home_Page/Kongoji_homepage.jpg" alt="Kongoji" width="40%"></a>
</div>
    
<br><br><footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px;">小泉© 2020年 | <a href="#">English</a></footer>
      
</div>
      
<style>
    
 .searchbar{float: right;}  
    

 
@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px){
    .responsive-image-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
    
 .setsumei{margin-left: 20px;
           margin-right: 20px;}
    
 .footer{width: 100%; 
           height: 40px; 
           text-align: center;
           border-top: 1px solid black; 
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 0;
           padding: 10px;}
    
 .page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -40px; 
}

 .page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; 
  }

 .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 40px; 
}

 .site-footer {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
        

 *, *:before, *:after {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}    

 ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
    
 .cp_cont {
    height: auto;
}
    
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
 .cp_offcm03 nav,
 .cp_offcm03 ul {
    height: 100%;
}

 .cp_offcm03 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -6px;
}

 .cp_offcm03 a {
    display: block;    
    padding: 15px 45px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
            transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
}
    
 .cp_offcm03 a:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* menu toggle */
 #cp_toggle03 {
    display: none;
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 .cp_mobilebar {
    display: none;
    
}

/* content */
 .cp_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    padding: 35px auto;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
            transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}   

 .cp_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 65vh;
    text-align: center;

}

@media (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 480px) {
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
        position: fixed;
        left: -250px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 40px;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 nav {
        background: white;
        border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
        margin-left: -210px;
    }
    
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 li {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0;}

        
        
 .cp_offcm03 a {
        padding: 20px;
        
    }
    
/* menu toggle */
 .cp_mobilebar {
        display: block;
        z-index: 2000;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 25px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;
        
        
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 25px;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55%;
        margin-top: -0.3em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0.2em;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease;
                transition: transform .3s ease;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span:before,
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon > span:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
                transform: translateY(-0.6em);
    }
 
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
                transform: translateY(0.6em);
    }

 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:before,
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
                transform: translateX(250px);
    }
    
 input:checked ~ #h-menu_black {
    display: block;/*カバーを表示*/
    opacity: .6;
}
    
 #h-menu_black {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
}
    
/* content */
 .cp_container {
        top: 60px;
        height: 92vh;
        text-align: center; 
    } 
    
 .noscroll{
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
</style> 
      
</body>
</html>




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkD6k.jpg
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Images are inline elements, if you know what is the max-width that you want them to take on bigger size screens, assign that and they will be side-by-side on bigger screens and one below the other on smaller screens automatically, you don't need to do anything. You shouldn't be using the table element for presentation.

Comment: No, I'm not using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Images are an [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements). It depends on how you want your layout to work, but you may not need to do anything, it may be as simple as using the proper image size and setting a max-size.

A very simple implementation of what you need:

```css
.responsive-image-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.responsive-image-container>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-image-container">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/any" alt="some image" />
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/any" alt="some image" />
</div>
```

A simple way to have more control, for example to have the images fill the containing parent, can be achieved using flex.

```css
.responsive-image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .responsive-image-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-image-container">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/any" alt="some image" />
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/any" alt="some image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This does help to line up the images one on top of another when on a smaller screen, but I find that on a bigger screen the size of the image on the right is small and the one on the left is big, as well as both pictures are not exactly right beside one another. Any way I can fix the image so they're the same size when lined up next to each other when displayed on a bigger screen?

Comment: Which of the two examples are you trying? In both cases the images are the same size for me, how are you running the examples? If you want the pictures to be next to each other, just remove the `margin: 8px` line on the CSS.

Comment: I've tried both codes and neither of them is giving me the results I'm looking for. The smaller screen looks fine, but the images aren't lined up properly on a maximized screen.

Comment: Where are you running the code? Are you mixing it up with your own code? The code above works fine, there is no CSS that affects their vertical position or size, so the problem is coming from somewhere else, can you send more details?

Comment: The problem is most likely from something in the code I'm using for my website. When I tried the above code on a separate page I was able to get it to work as it should, I just wasn't able to center the images once they were lined up in a column.

Comment: You can use grid for that.

Comment: I've revised the code and posted it above. I've played around with it and gotten the images to line up on top of each other on a smaller screen, but they're too far spaced out and for whatever reason, they end up being too small to view properly. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you have everything wrapped up on another div with inline styles? `<div class="image" style="margin: 10px; text-align: center;">` I have no way to check, since the images that you are using are not available, but that is probably influencing the styles. You have a lot of random CSS on that page, I would suggest starting with the clean `div` and adding more elements gradually until something breaks, then you know where the problem is.